# Python how to make fast multiprocessing program?

Tags: python, pyqt5, multiprocessing

I made a simple GUI tool controlling a robot but there was GUI lock up during robot was operating.
I added sub-process taking whole robot controlling.
After adding sub-process, GUI lock up was cleared.
However it takes very long time to see the response of robot after sending command.
Sometimes it takes a few seconds.
Before adding sub-process, it didn't exceed hundreds milliseconds at max.

I implemented sub-process like below.
GUI put command in the cmd_q of sub-process.
Sub-process is activated in GUI init.
Is there any way to improve the response speed?

```py
class ProcRobotControl(Process):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.daemon = True
        self.cmd_q = Queue()

    def run(self):
        while True:
            while self.cmd_q.empty():
                pass

            cmd = self.cmd_q.get()
```

Comment: Please provide a [mre], as right now your code is completely insufficient to understand the problem. Also, if controlling the robot is just a matter of I/O calls, you probably don't need multiprocessing, as threading (possibly via the QThread interface) will suffice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So-called "busy-waiting" (your line while self.cmd_q.empty():) is discouraged in most situations, because the waiting process will eat resources. If the event that your process is waiting for is created on the same machine, then your waiting process actually prevents the event from being created quickly.

If that is indeed the problem (impossible for me to test without more code) then a quick-and-dirty solution would be to replace the "pass" in the busy-wait with an "os.sched_yield()", thus making your waiting-thread relinquish the cpu and allow the gui-thread to do work.

Cleaner suggestion using **multiprocessing**:
The default-behaviour of a multiprocessing Queue's get is to block until an element is available (see here: https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.Queue.get), so you can skip the unreliable queue.empty()-check altogether

Cleaner suggestion using **pyqt5**: The framework already has its own threading-solution with the QThread object. This is probably better for preventing bad interactions with the gui-loop, so try if it solves your problem.

Comment: I'll try to use "os.sched_yield()" instead of "pass". By the way, you pointed clearner suggestion for mutiprocessing Queue's get. If I remove "while self.cmd_q.emtpy()", where should I put "os.sched_yield()"?

Comment: you do not need to explicitly call sched_yield if you dont busy-wait for the queue to be non-empty. The get-call itself will wait. It probably has some loop with sched_yield or something similar in its implementation.

Comment: I added "os.sched_yield()" but saw this message "AttributeError: module 'os' has no attribute 'sched_yield' ". Python version is 3.9. Anything should I check?

Comment: @JerryKim apparently os.sched_yield() is not available on all platforms. It works on linux, but not windows. But anyways: os.sched_yield() is just a trick to find out if the problem is what I think it is. You can completely drop the loop checking for emptyness of the queue.

Answer (score 0):

Just to provide additional info provided in the answer posted by julaine:

First, you should read carefully the [documentation for the `multiprocessing.Queue`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html?highlight=multiprocessing%20queue#multiprocessing.Queue). You will see that it clearly states that the `empty` method is not reliable. You should not be using this in general and definitely not the way you are using it, which is non-productive CPU-cycle burning.

Based on the minimal code that you have posted, I see no reason to even test to see whether there is an item in the queue; you should just be doing a blocking `get`:

```py
    def run(self):
        while True:
            cmd = self.cmd_q.get() # blocking get is the default here
```

In this way you are not burning up CPU cycles waiting for the next command.

I would also recommend not deriving your class from class `multiprocessing.Process`, which limits its reusability. For example, you might want to use the same logic with threading instead of multiprocessing, substituting q `queue.Queue` instance for a `multiprocessing.Queue` or `multiprocessing.JoinableQueue` instance:

```py
class ProcRobotControl:
    def __init__(self, cmd_q):
        self.cmd_q = cmd_q

    def run(self):
        while True:
            cmd = self.cmd_q.get()
            print(cmd)
            self.cmd_q.task_done()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    # Use ProcRobot as a child process:
    import multiprocessing

    q1 = multiprocessing.JoinableQueue()
    proc_robot_control = ProcRobotControl(q1)
    p = multiprocessing.Process(target=proc_robot_control.run, daemon=True)
    p.start()
    q1.put('a')
    q1.put('b')
    # Wait for all commands to be procssed:
    q1.join()

    # Use ProcRobot as a child thread:
    import threading
    import queue

    q2 = queue.Queue()
    proc_robot_control = ProcRobotControl(q2)
    t = threading.Thread(target=proc_robot_control.run, daemon=True)
    t.start()
    q2.put('c')
    q2.put('d')
    # Wait for all commands to be procssed:
    q2.join()
```